# Trying to get property of non-object Error

Tags: laravel

I have this error Trying to get property of non-object

```
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\DigitalStudio\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
in b1747510b3c408d907ba1958669ebd058ad57227.php (line 101)
```

and the line that pointed out is this line

```
<img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::User()->avatar }}" class="img-circle person" alt="Random Name" width="255" height="255">
```

is there any  wrong or mistake in my code ? in my other page profile and this is my profile page image tag

```
 <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::User()->avatar }}" style="width:150px; height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
```

Comment: seems `{{Auth::User()->avatar}}` don't have data for avatar

Comment: id use that code in my profile(admin)  page and it works but when i try to put in my User page it  gives me error

Comment: Check before get Auth property `if (Auth::check()) { 'You are logged in'; }`

Comment: @KurtPino admin and user both are different user, Right?

Comment: @Hari it fix my problem sir ,  when i log in my user in admin page then when i looked into user page the page run smoothly without error and the image display

Comment: Thank you so much Guys  for the help..

i got an idea  so i wont get this error

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya i already solve it  Sir thank you for the help i appreciated so much

Answer (score 1):

You should always check if a user is authenticated:

```
@if (auth()->check())
    <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ auth()->user()->avatar }}" style="width:150px; height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
@else
    Please login
@endif
```